# Command to re-enable decoration on windows

Tags: xorg, openbox

I'm running openbox, I have accidentally undecorated a window (By clicking on `Un/Decorate`)

Now is it possible to restore the decoration?

Since the title is "invisible" now, I have no where to click on. Perhaps there's a Xorg command to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Window menu aka *client menu for active window* should be [accessible trough](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:DefaultConfiguration):
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

then toggle by:

- enter <kbd>d</kbd>, or
- navigate to `Un/Decorate` by arrow keys, or
- click on menu entry with pointer.

[image: Openbox Un/Decorate menu example on undecorated window]

---

---

Tested on:

- Openbox
- GNOME/Openbox
- KDE/Openbox

Though KDE use [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Window_management) as Window menu shortcut, <kbd>space</kbd> works with Openbox under KDE as well.